# VS2013 собирает проект каждый раз с нуля

Tags: visual-studio

Случайно нажал какое-то сочетание клавиш и теперь проект каждый раз собирается с нуля, как при ребилде. Даже если я его только что собрал, ничего не менял и нажал опять собрать.

Пытался найти эту функцию в опциях - не получилось. Может кто подскажет, как отключить это?

Comment: А если создать новый проект, с ним тот же эффект?

Comment: @VladD нет, только с тем, в котором что-то нажал.

Comment: Окей, а если сделать Rebuild проекту?

Comment: @VladD делал и ребилд и клин. Всегда с нуля потом билд

Comment: @VladD зажатый ctrl и рука положенная на левую часть клавиатуры решили проблему.

Comment: Оригинальный метод решения :) Но раз помог — то помог.